# How do I find the amount of memory allocated by a method?

Tags: .net, profiling, memory-management

I'd like to know the total amount of memory allocated while a method runs. So far I have:

```
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
memStart = GC.GetTotalMemory(false)
f()
memEnd = GC.GetTotalMemory(false)
print (memEnd - memStart)
```

This seems to work well enough for simple functions but when `f` allocates so much that it forces a collection then the result excludes the already collected objects. Not only that, there is no way of telling that this "overflow" happened.

Is there an easy way to do this? Without buying/installing/configuring a memory profiler? Something like a Stopwatch for the allocator/collector would be ideal. So I could do:

```
sw = new GCStopwatch()
sw.Start()
f()
sw.Stop()
print sw.TotalBytesAllocated
print sw.NumberOfCollections
// etc
```

I want this so I can find out how much pressure a method is putting on the garbage collector. My code is reading numbers from a fixed length string using lots of calls along the lines of `Int32.Parse(s.Substring(4,6))` and I considered doing the parsing in-place by introducing `ParseInt(String s, int startIndex, int length)` to avoid allocating tens of thousands of substrings. But this would be a nice tool to have in other scenarios too.

Comment: If `f` allocated lots of small objects, such that it caused a collection, and lots of those objects were freed... Good - the .NET memory system is working well, and with one of its main assumptions - that a lot of recently allocated objects can be freed. To put it another way, why are you trying to second-guess the allocator and garbage collector?

Comment: @Damien: I am not trying to second guess or influence the GC in any way. I just want some statistics about allocations/collections within a given period ie. a lightweight profiling class.

Comment: @petebu - I was more looking at your final paragraph, where you were thinking of re-writing framework functionality to avoid allocating those substrings.

Comment: @Damien: But the choice is between lots of small short-lived allocations and none at all at very little cost. ParseInt is just as readable as Int32.Parse and the implementation is pretty simple and won't ever change (zero maintenance). I have nothing against the .NET memory system but in this case the allocations seem gratuitous. To put it another way, if ParseInt was part of the BCL, this would be a no brainer.

Comment: @petebu - when you do find a profiler you like, you might be surprised at the relative efficiencies of `Int32.Parse` and `String.Substring`. If your suggested `ParseInt` was part of the BCL, it would presumably have to cope with the same range of possibilities as `Int32.Parse`, e.g. different cultures, `NumberStyles` and `IFormatProvider` options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used performance counters for these kind of analysis. Not perfect but usually good enough.

```
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Those two lines won't wait for the Garbage collector to actually finish. And a garbage collection might occur during you're function call anyway. It might be better to just measure performance/time as an optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that you don't want to use a memory profiler, but this is exactly the sort of situation that one is useful in. Just download something like [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), and use the 14 day free trial. It should give you a fairly instant picture of what's going on.